# How to combine text and a field value in a single line of display

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I am using Vega and I am stuck on this simple issue. I want to display

`The yield is 43.67%`

However using the samples provided I have managed to just display the value 43.67

```
{
  mark:
    {
      type: "text",
      align: "center",
      fontSize: 40,
      fontWeight: "bold"
    },
  encoding: 
    {
      "text": {"field": "Yield", "type": "quantitative",format: ".2f"}
    }
}
```

Is it possible to add some text in front of this value and put a % sign after it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

THe best way to add this sort of complicated annotation is using a [calculate transform](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/calculate.html); for example:

```json
{
  mark:
    {
      type: "text",
      align: "center",
      fontSize: 40,
      fontWeight: "bold"
    },
  transform:
    [
      {"calculate": "'The yield is ' + datum.Yield + '%'", "as": "annotated_yield"}
    ],
  encoding: 
    {
      "text": {"field": "annotated_yield", "type": "nominal"}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Can you suggest how I put that .2f format option in?

Comment: I fixed it at time of calculate operation. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you figured out another way, but you can format using the format function of Vega expressions, so `{"calculate": "'The yield is ' + format(datum.Yield, '.2f') + '%'", "as": "annotated_yield"}`. Documentation here: https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/#format

Comment: This is great! I am also curious how we can specify `tooltipHandler` in vega-lite json above. The [doc says](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/tooltip.html#plugin) "You can further customize the tooltip by specifying a custom event handler via tooltipHandler of the Vega View API." There is not a single example of this anywhere online!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is wondering how to do this with Vega (instead of Vega-Lite):

```
  "transform": [
    {"type": "formula", "expr": "'The yield is ' + format(datum.Yield, '.2f') + '%'", "as": "annotated_yield"}
  ]
```